# Java Formatter - what is '#' for?

Tags: java, string, formatting

According to [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html), the '#' flag stands for "*The result should use a conversion-dependent alternate form*". I wasn't able to find any details on that. Could someone explain what is the "*conversion-dependent alternate form*"?

Comment: That depends on each conversion. There's more information on that further down in the Java doc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are examples given in the javadoc.

eg for an integer being output as octal,

> If the '#' flag is given then the output will always begin with the
>   radix indicator '0'.

or as hex,

> If the '#' flag is given then the output will always begin with the
>   radix indicator "0x".

For floating-point numbers,

> If the '#' flag is given, then the decimal separator will always be
>   present.